# How would you describe a character in heavy armor taking damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, narration

In order to properly describe combat Id like a clearer understanding of what it look like when a player in plate armor takes damage.

> PHB 5e. Plate consists of shaped, interlocking metal plates to cover the entire body. A suit of plate includes gauntlets, heavy leather boots, a visored helmet, and thick layers of padding underneath the armor. Buckles and straps distribute the weight over the body.

That seems very durable. Does an enemy mace dent the armor and hit the person within? Can a sword pierce the plate?

How do you see your DM describing a character in full plate taking a damaging hit?

Comment: Sorry, newbie, this question will generate a _lot_ of opinionated answers, and  all of them would be equally correct. You might try a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) instead.

Answer (score 5):

From the SRD:

> Hit points represent a combination of physical and mental durability, the will to live, and luck.

An attack that reduces hit points of a heavily armored creature need not result in any physical wounds. Instead it can drain the creature's stamina and durability, or it's willingness to continue fighting for it's own life. The way any individual reduction of hit points is described is up to the DM of that particular game.

Answer (score -1):

I would go to my favourite source: le morte d'Arthur. 
For example: "Sir Lancelot drew put his sword and struck him such a buffet on the helmet that he clave the head and neck unto the throat." Or for a less than fatal stroke: "And when he saw them come he smote a sore stroke unto Sir Arnold, that he fell from his horse to the ground, and then he struck at the other two brethren, and at two strokes he strake them down to the earth." Could be power attack and cleave.

"And so he met him on a plain and gave him such a buffet that he was astonied,  that long he wist not where he was." Stunning blow.